# Simple_form adding class to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form in my Rails application, I tried to add `form-horizontal` class to my form.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/account/orders" class="simple_form new_order" data-validate="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_order" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

When I use `html: { class: "form-horizontal" }` it change `class="simple_form new_order"` to `class="simple_form form-horizontal"`.

What should I do to keep `new_order` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [intended behaviour](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/1e8bba7eb378da86cabb3d6a0ece9b34998c58e2).

So if you want to change it you should monkey-patch `simple_form_css_class` method in [this file](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb).

Answer (score 65):

it works for me like this

```
= simple_form_for @model, html: { class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  ...
```

it compiles to

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/numbers" class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="new_number" method="post">
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this question was asked in Dec 2012. According to the version history, https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form/versions, Simple Form 3 had not been released yet. In Simple Form 2, this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me `config.form_class = 'form-horizontal'` and keep new_model class

Comment: The obvious drawback to this is now every form has this class, which is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_html: { class: "form-horizontal"}
```

works fine in rails 7