# simple_form class not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am trying to create a form using Simple Form.  For some reason, I can't change the class of the form.  I am using the following code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @presentation, url: send_out_emails_path, 
    defaults: {input_html: { :class => 'form-horizontal' } } do |f| %>
    <!-- Form content here !-->
<% end %>
```

It is generating this html:

```
<form action="/sendout" class="simple_form edit_presentation" id="edit_presentation_152" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
     <!-- Form content here !-->
</form>
```

Why is the class not being changed?

Comment: Are you saying you want the `form` element's `class` to change?  It looks to me like the code you've provided may change the `input` elements' `class` of that form.

Comment: The `input_html` hash key is for setting the input HTML element items. The format I've seen for setting the class to `form-horizontal` is: `simple_form_for @presentation, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| ...`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903175/simple-form-adding-class-to-form